# Warning: include(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration

Tags: php, wordpress, cpanel

i'm trying to create a plugin in wordpress
that's my code

```
 include plugins_url("/imp-file/admin/partials/imp-file-admin-display.php");
```

and that's the warning

```
> Warning: include(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server
> configuration by allow_url_include=0 in
> /home/darelizza/public_html/wp-content/plugins/imp-file/admin/class-imp-file-admin.php
> on line 120
> 
> Warning:
> include(http://darelizza.com/wp-content/plugins/imp-file/admin/partials/imp-file-admin-display.php):
> failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in
> /home/darelizza/public_html/wp-content/plugins/imp-file/admin/class-imp-file-admin.php
> on line 120
> 
> Warning: include(): Failed opening
> 'http://darelizza.com/wp-content/plugins/imp-file/admin/partials/imp-file-admin-display.php'
> for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in
> /home/darelizza/public_html/wp-content/plugins/imp-file/admin/class-imp-file-admin.php
> on line 120
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use plugins_url. Try this:

```
include plugins_dir_path("/imp-file/admin/partials/imp-file-admin-
display.php");
```

Comment: i tried and that's the error Call to undefined function plugins_dir_path()

Comment: function plugin_dir_path( $file ) {
    return trailingslashit( dirname( $file ) );
} and  plugins_dir_path("/imp-file/admin/partials/imp-file-admin-
display.php"); thank youuu

Comment: Sorry, ive forgot the $file

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a structure that defines plugin path variable in your base class:

   `define( 'XPlugin_PLUGIN_PATH', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) );`
2. and then use it like a param from your `include` function as follows:

   `include( XPlugin_PLUGIN_PATH. '/admin/partials/XPlugin-admin-display.php');`